# save and load random number is not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to generate a random number in first start of app and and show it in a text view. Also I need the random text saved and loaded for next start of the app.

So this is the code I'n trying:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);

       onResume(); {
         super.onResume();

         if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {

              Random r = new Random();
               int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;

               SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
               editor.putInt("random id", i1);
               editor.commit();


             prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();

         }
     }

       SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
       int myIntValue = sp.getInt("random id", -1);


       TextView iddd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
       iddd.setText(myIntValue);
      }
```

But this code won't work...
What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

log:

```
09-12 12:27:27.203: E/test(10532): Exception
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hhh/com.example.hhh.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x43
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x43
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3805)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at com.example.hhh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
09-12 12:27:27.205: E/AndroidRuntime(10532):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please explain **but this code won't work**
what is your expected result and what result are you getting?

Comment: @SripadRaj it just show nothing in the text view...

Comment: @J Doe Add 
String valueInt = Integer.toString(myIntValue );
iddd.setText(valueInt );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x43
> ```

at

> ```
> iddd.setText(myIntValue);
> ```

Use e.g.

```
iddd.setText(String.valueOf(myIntValue));
```

`setText(int)` expects to see a resource string id; `setText(CharSequence)` is the one you want to call.